# JSON decode with un-escaped double quotes

Tags: python, json

Refer to the below response JSON from source. Source is not flexible to make changes at their end. The challenge is to decode the key value pair within "result".

```
{"result":"{\"key1\" : \"value with \"n,a.\".\" , \"key2\":\"value with \"n.a.\".\" }"}
```

Nested JSON within result:

```
{"key1" : "value with "n,a."." , "key2":"value with "n.a."."}
```

I am using python for decoding.

```
json_string = '{\"result\":\"{\\"key1\\" : \\"value with \\"n,a.\\".\\" , \\"key2\\":\\"value with \\"n.a.\\".\\"}\"}'

#The following string with no double quotes within value part works as expected
#json_string = '{\"result\":\"{\\"key1\\" : \\"value with n,a.\\" , \\"key2\\":\\"value with n.a. .\\"}\"}'

data1 = json.loads(json_string)

data1['result']
# '{"key1" : "value with "n,a."." , "key2":"value with "n.a."."}'

data_dict_string = data1['result']
json_stringp = "[{0}]".format(data_dict_string)
data_list = json.loads(json_stringp)
```

The presence of double quotes as expected results in the following error,

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

How to remove double quotes within the value part of JSON?

Comment: The JSON from "source" is broken, might be beyond automated repair.

Comment: Source has accepted the flaw but stated that they can't handle it at their end

Comment: Well they violated the standard, they fix it. It is that simple. And one of the things you learn in computer science first is that statement don't need to be true.

Comment: you could also write some heuristic to fix it on your end, but it's guaranteed to fail in some special cases. E.g. you could have `", " .... ": "` as text inside the value which is totally legitimate and without any further understanding of the content you cannot tell if this is just part of the value or defines a new key, value pair. Standards are there for a reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks a technical solution to a organizational (if not _legal_) problem.

Comment: IMHO a fellow programmer can still seek advice from developer community on the challenge he is facing irrespective of the classification

Comment: Well yes. And the advice is, fix the data source so it produces output compliant with the widely recognised and implemented international standard format for JSON. If people responsible won't accept that they've made a mistake in that respect then and/or will not put it right you need to find a way to put pressure on them. It should not be a hard thing to fix. IMO it's borderline whether this is actually a programming question or not. You should not need to write any special code to deal with JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using Enumerator. Sharing the link to the asked to answer solution
[Replace escaped double quotes to single quotes in Python using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081203/replace-escaped-double-quotes-to-single-quotes-in-python-using-regex/58081464?noredirect=1#comment102627707_58081464)

Solution code:

```
import json
js = r'{"result":"{\"key\":\"How are you? \"Great!\" he said. \"Coffee ?\"\"},{\"key\":\" 2. \"Why not, sure.\". They walked away\"}"}'

data1 = json.loads(js)
s = data1['result']

good_characters = [":","{","}",","]
result = "" 

for key, value in enumerate(s):

    if ((value == "\"" and s[key-1] not in good_characters) and (value == "\"" and s[key+1] not in good_characters) or (value == "\"" and s[key-1] == "," and s[key-2] != "\"")):
        result += '\''   
    else:
        result += value        
#print(result)
json_string = "[{0}]".format(result)
data_list = json.loads(json_string)
print(data_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: There might be an actual solution, detailed below.**

Their JSON is definitely completely broken, and in a normal scenario this shouldn't be on you to fix.

There's no safe way to reverse this corruption because, as you can see, information is lost when the escape characters get stripped, so the result is ambiguous:

`"{\"abc\": \"def\": \"ghi\"}"` could mean either `"{\"abc\": \"def\\": \\"ghi\"}"` (value is `def": "ghi`) or `"{\"abc\\": \\"def\": \"ghi\"}"` (key is `abc": "def`)

There are some heuristics you could apply, provided that the data structure is fairly simple and doesn't contain any other problems.

For example, if the structure is flat and the keys are all alphanumeric, you can try to identify the potential keys (`/(\{|\\", )\\"([a-z]+)\\": \\"/`), and then try to parse the stuff between/after them as values.

If there may be nested objects (let alone if any of the strings contain further badly encoded JSON), it gets more complicated.

Basically, this goes beyond "flaw" - you're trying to unscramble an egg here.

---

**Addendum**: Computer Science wise, I guess it is *technically* possible to describe this problem and potentially even solve it (ie. enumerate the possible candidate structures that may be decoded from a given string, which are hopefully few, and which you could then further validate to find the right one). JSON is described by a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and removing the escape characters turns it into an [ambiguous grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar) (ie, a grammar that has multiple syntax trees producing the same string). There are parsing algorithms that handle this in (at worst) cubic time O(n^3).

As far as I can tell, GNU Bison implements this parser, and it's available as a Python library: http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pybison/

So if you have no other option and can  formalize the grammar of "broken JSON", that may end up being the most robust (but also quite complex) approach in the end.

Comment: I am looking for similar heuristics. Isolating value for the 2nd key should still be possible using regex.