# Replace escaped double quotes to single quotes in Python using regex

Tags: python, json, regex

I am trying to replace escaped double quotes to single quotes in a key value pair

```
import re
import json
js = r'{"result":"{\"key\":\"How are you? \"Great!\" he said. \"Coffee ?\"\"},{\"key\":\" 2. \"Why not sure\". They walked away\"}"}'
#print(js)
data1 = json.loads(js)
s = data1['result']
#print(s)
# {"key":"How are you? "Great!" he said. "Coffee ?""},{"key":" 2. "Why not, sure.". They walked away"}
p = re.compile(r"\"key\":\"(.*\"(.*)\".*)\"")
print(p.sub(r'\'\2\'',s))
# {\'Why not, sure.\'}
json_string = "[{0}]".format(p.sub(r'\'\1\'',s))
data_list = json.loads(json_string)
```

With the above code, I got an output \'Coffee ?\' instead of the entire string. I would like to replace the double quote only within the value part.

**String :** "key":"How are you? "Great!" he said. "Coffee ?"",

**Expected String :** "key":"How are you? 'Great!' he said. 'Coffee ?'",

Comment: Is RegEX a strict requirement?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/aOTAry.

Comment: That's not the intended one. I need the double quotes within value part be replaced with single quotes.

Comment: Would it be possible to look at the full json you get (I suppose) in input?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible. Let me know what aspects you want to check ?

Comment: If your json is complete and parsable you don't need to use RegEX to access the key and modify it.

Comment: I've written an example for you. The more precise input data you provide the more it will be easy to help. You can sanitize it and write gibberish instead of real data but the structure must be identical.

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON is not parsable. I am trying to recover such a badly stored data. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is just following the comments we've exchanged:

```
import json
js = r'{"result":"{\"key\":\"How are you? \"Great!\" he said. \"Coffee ?\"\"},{\"key\":\" 2. \"Why not sure\". They walked away\"}"}'
data1 = json.loads(js)
s = data1['result']

good_characters = [":","{","}", ","]
result = "" 
for key, value in enumerate(s):
    if (value == "\"" and s[key-1] not in good_characters) and (value == "\"" and s[key+1] not in good_characters):
        result += '\''  
    else:
        result += value

print (result)
```

Output

```
{"key":"How are you? 'Great!' he said. 'Coffee ?'"},{"key":" 2. 'Why not sure'. They walked away"}
```

Comment: The JSON you get is the following : {"key":"How are you? "Great!" he said. "Coffee ?""},{"key":" 2. "Why not, sure.". They walked away"}

Comment: Hi @NareshS
This seems different from the code in your question.
If you share an example identical to your data I can work on a possible solution.

Comment: Hi @Pitto - I had updated the code. Refer to the 8th line. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks. I added "," part of the good character list.

Comment: Very happy it worked for you, also added the change to my answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If the key is consistent across the string then this would work

```
s = data1['result']
','.join([d[:8] + d[8:-2].replace('"',"'") + d[-2:] for d in s.split(',')])
```

Comment: This is the value I get when I print : {"key":"How are you? 'Great!' he said. 'Coffee ?'"},{"key":" 2. 'Why not, sure.". They walked away"}